# Multiple search in Laravel using DataTables

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, search, datatable

I am developing an application, where I have to fulfill several search conditions 
(search by product, by family...etc.)

In the MySQL database using Laravel with DataTables. I have to switch between the conditions without updating the entire page, like changing pages in Excel. How can I apply only one condition at a time, then perform a search and display the result in DataTables?

Comment: Are you searching by datatable default search text box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` function on DataTable read [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()):-

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var filteredData = table
    .column( 0 )
    .data()
    .filter( function ( value, index ) {
        return value > 20 ? true : false;
    } );
```